# Не получается вставить изображение в option

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, html-select

Поставить `background` в `option` не получается.
К примеру, вот есть такой `option`:

```css
.flag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: auto;
  width: 18px;
  height: 13px;
}
.city_flags.flag {
  width: 97px;
  height: 16px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #3F51B5;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 0 0 23px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #3F51B5;
}
.flag_AZ {
  background: no-repeat url(http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/flags.png) 0px -664px;
}
.flag_UZ {
  background: no-repeat url(http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/flags.png) 0px -3314px;
}
.flag_TUR {
  background: no-repeat url(http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/flags.png) 0px -579px;
}
.flag_UK {
  background: no-repeat url(http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/flags.png) 0px -34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="city_flags flag flag_AZ" id="user_language" onchange="set_lang(this.value)&amp;set_lang_dis();">
  <option class="city_flags flag flag_AZ" id="Azerbaijan" value="Azerbaijan" slected="selected">Azərbaycan</option>
  <option class="city_flags flag flag_TR" id="Azerbaijan" value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
  <option class="city_flags flag flag_US" id="Azerbaijan" value="American" slected="selected">American</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/ru.png);" class="city_flags" id="Azerbaijan" value="Russian" disabled="disabled" slected="selected">Russian</option>
  <option class="city_flags flag flag_IT" id="Azerbaijan" value="Italy">Italy</option>
</select>
```

По-разному ставлю — всё равно не показывается картинка в `option`, а в `select` видно. И еще при выборе `option` имя вставляется в `select`, а картинка — нет. 
Как правильно сделать, чтобы в каждому `option` рядом с именем страны показывался флаги при выборе вместе с именем вставился в `select`.

Comment: Чтобы было кроссбраузерно - делайте *select* через *ul* к примеру, и обработчик на *jquery* простенький к нему напишите. Или поищите плагины на том же *jquery* которые предоставляют свои варианты селектов. На стандартном сделать вроде невозможно.

Comment: @Moonvvell  а как сделать **select через ul** покажите пример пожалуйста.. а то я со скриптами не  очень,

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Такое стандартными средствами не сделать, но уже есть готовые решения типа: [такого селекта](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick)
Настройка очень проста.
Есть множество и других рабочих скриптов

Answer (score 0):

Стандартным select такое сделать, скорее всего, не получится.
Как говорилось выше - можно либо самому написать обертку для , либо использовать что-либо готовое.

Как вариант - jQueryUI:
https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Comment: спасибо за ответь я уже нашел отличную решению [вот если кому нужно будет](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)