# Картинка перед выбранным текстом в select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как можно вставить картинку (календарик) перед выбранным месяцем в select?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш код, чтобы можно было понять как в вашем случае реализовано и что с этим можно сделать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505511/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-option